# Allow only one click on login button

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My company's main web site is in Drupal 7. It's a complicated site, and we are handling authentication separately from Drupal. Our back-end developer asked me to ensure that the Login button can be clicked only once. Apparently if you click it multiple times it causes problems with our authentication process.

We're using the standard Drupal login form. I tried disabling the button in a click event handler, but that causes the entire event to not fire, so no login happens. I tried using jQuery's #one function, that is supposed to fire the handler only once, but this did not work. The handler I created with #one did indeed fire only once, but multiple clicks on the button still went through to the login routine.

Basically I want to allow the button to be clicked only once, then the login process should happen, and after processing, the button should be re-enabled so they can click it again (in case they enter the wrong password, for instance.)

I'm not sure how to attach Javascript to the built-in form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) to [modify the user login form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-can-i-modify-the-login-form-using-hook-form-alter). To attach JS to any form using form alter you can add an #attached element to the array:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
```

See also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70015/adding-css-and-js-to-form-with-attachments